# align is aligning to the right

Tags: align

I would like to align the + and the if's below eachother but for some reason the ifs all get aligned to the right even though I used the &. I don't understand why this is happening and I would like to know how to fix it such that the ifs come under each other.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\left\{\begin{align*}
        f(x) \quad &+ \quad g(x) & \text{ if } f(x)\geq 0 \text{, } g(x)     \geq 0 \\
        0 \quad &+ \quad 0 & \text{ if } f(x)\geq 0 \text{, } g(x) < -f(x) \\
        f(x)-(-g(x)) \quad &+ \quad 0 & \text{ if } f(x)\geq 0 \text{, } -f(x) \leq g(x) < 0 \\
        0 \quad &+ \quad 0 & \text{ if } f(x)<0 \text{, } g(x)< 0 \\
        \end{align*}
        \right.
\end{equation*}
```

[image: align]

Comment: Maybe you have to use something other than `align`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You should not have `\begin{align*}` inside `\begin{equation*}... \end{equation*}` , did you mean to use `aligned`?

Comment: I did use aligned before, I tried to use align as a fix but didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first, third, fifth, ... `&` left-align the following expressions, while the second, fourth, sixth, ... `&` right-align the following expressions. Your solution here: Use `&&` instead of `&` at the second appearance in each line:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left\{\begin{aligned}
        f(x) \quad &+ \quad g(x) && \text{ if } f(x)\geq 0 \text{, } g(x)     \geq 0 \\
        0 \quad &+ \quad 0 && \text{ if } f(x)\geq 0 \text{, } g(x) < -f(x) \\
        f(x)-(-g(x)) \quad &+ \quad 0 && \text{ if } f(x)\geq 0 \text{, } -f(x) \leq g(x) < 0 \\
        0 \quad &+ \quad 0 && \text{ if } f(x)<0 \text{, } g(x)< 0 \\
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this also extend to &&& if theres another thing to align on ?

Comment: No. If you only care about left-aligning stuff, then the first occurence gets a single `&` and every consequent one a `&&`.

Answer (score 3):

I see no reason for aligning at the + sign, but perhaps you have.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Alignment at $+$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
f(x)         &+ g(x) &\qquad& \text{if $f(x)\geq 0$, $g(x)\geq 0$} \\
0            &+ 0    &\qquad& \text{if $f(x)\geq 0$, $g(x) < -f(x)$} \\
f(x)-(-g(x)) &+ 0    &\qquad& \text{if $f(x)\geq 0$, $-f(x) \leq g(x) < 0$} \\
0            &+ 0    &\qquad& \text{if $f(x)<0$, $g(x)< 0$}
\end{alignedat}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Better with no artificial alignment?
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
f(x) + g(x)      & \text{if $f(x)\geq 0$, $g(x)\geq 0$} \\
0 + 0            & \text{if $f(x)\geq 0$, $g(x) < -f(x)$} \\
f(x)-(-g(x)) + 0 & \text{if $f(x)\geq 0$, $-f(x) \leq g(x) < 0$} \\
0 + 0            & \text{if $f(x)<0$, $g(x)< 0$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The top display could have been simply managed with `aligned`, but because of the alignment at +, I think it's better to have more space between the two parts. Try with `aligned` and `&&` instead of `&\qquad&`.

Answer (score 2):

That's the normal behaviour if you specify alignment points with an ampersand: it is implicitly added at the end of each line. Furthermore, n columns of alignment require 2n–1 ampersands: one ampersang to introduce each new column but the first, and one ampersand to set the alignment point inside that column.

I also propose a simpler code, with the `empheq` package (wich loads `amthtools`, which loads `amsmath`). I suppose this is what you want:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

    \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
        f(x) \quad &+ \quad g(x) &\text{ if }& f(x)\geq 0,\ g(x) \geq 0 \\
        0 \quad &+ \quad 0 & \text{ if } & f(x)\geq 0 ,\ g(x) < -f(x) \\
        f(x)-(-g(x)) \quad &+ \quad 0 & \text{ if } & f(x)\geq 0 ,\ -f(x) \leq g(x) < 0 \\
        0 \quad &+ \quad 0 & \text{ if } & f(x)<0 ,\ g(x)< 0 \\
   \end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

with use of `array`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl @{\qquad}r l}
        f(x) & + & g(x) & \text{if }    & f(x)\geq 0,\ g(x) \geq 0 \\
          0  & + & 0    & \text{if }    & f(x)\geq 0,\ g(x) < -f(x) \\
f(x)-(-g(x)) & + & 0    & \text{if }    & f(x)\geq 0,\ -f(x) \leq g(x) < 0 \\
        0    & + & 0    & \text{if }    & f(x)<0 ,\ g(x)< 0 \\
   \end{array}\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]